# rendering extJs from webapp on tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, extjs

As a newbie to extJs ,am trying to configure a webapp to use it.
The justdoit.jsp is as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<html> 
<head>       
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extJs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />       
<script src="extJs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>       
<script src="extJs/ext-all.js"></script>       
<title>Getting Started with Extjs</title>       
<script type="text/javascript">       
// Path to the blank image must point to a valid location on your server     
Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'extJs/resources/images/default/s.gif';       
</script>   
</head> 
<body>
Ext.onReady(function(){
     Ext.Msg.alert('Test Extjs', 'Hello World'); }
     ); 
</body> 
</html>
```

The exploded structure of the war is :

```
justdoit.jsp
extJs/ext-all.js
extJs/adapter 
extJs/resources
META-INF
WEB-INF
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

However,the jsp gets rendered with literals,instead of any meaningful extJs phenomenon:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ Ext.Msg.alert('Test Extjs', 'Hello World'); } );
```

Whats wrong?
Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onReady` must be inside a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag.

Then you should create an eventual `<div id="grid">` or whatever, and in your `<script>` part create the ExtJS structures linked to `grid`.

Comment: silly oversight - The final script is as follows:                  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<html> 
<head>       
<title>Hello World</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extJs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script src="extJs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extJs/ext-all.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 Ext.onReady(function(){
     Ext.Msg.alert('Test Extjs', 'Hello World'); }
  ); 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>

Comment: @IUnknown, happens to everybody. Btw, could you please also vote up the answer. Thanks.